# If $(v_1, ... , v_m)$ is linear independent in $V$, then there exist a linear function $f: V\to W$ with $f(v_i)=w_i$ for arbitrary $w_i \in W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I found this interesting theorem in a text on linear algebra but unfortunately I do not understand the given proof. Hopefully nothing is lost in the translation. If anything is unclear, please let me know.

> Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces of finite dimension $n$ over a field $F$.
>
> If $(v_1, ... , v_m)$ is linear independent in $V$, then there exists a linear function $f: V\to W$ with $f(v_i)=w_i$ for arbitrary $w_i \in W$; $i = 1, ..., m$.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> We augment $(v_1, ... , v_m)$ to a basis $(v_1, ... , v_m, v_{m+1}, ... , v_n)$ of $V$ and set for all $a_1, ... , a_n \in F$: $$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i w_i.  $$ In particular, $f(v_i)=w_i$ holds for $i=1, ..., m$ and $f(v_i)=0$ holds for $i=m+1, ..., n$. Since there is a uniquely determined $a_1, ..., a_n$ for every $v \in V$  such that $v= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$ holds, $f$ is a well-defined function $f: V\to W$.
>
> Let $v, v'\in V$ with $v= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$ and $v'= \sum_{i=1}^n a'_i v_i$: $$f(v+v')= \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i+a'_i) w_i=f(v)+f(v'). $$ Similarly we show that $f(av)=a f(v)$ holds for $a \in F$. Thus $f$ is a linear function.

I do not understand what is going on the first two paragraphs of this proof. I know that every linear independent set of vectors can be augmented until it is a basis (in this context), but why is this useful here? Why does the first equality hold?

The last part is clear since we are simply checking if the properties of a linear function hold.

Comment: The first equality in the proof is the definition of the function $f$.  Before giving this definition, one has to know that every vector in $V$ can be uniquely expressed as $\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$; that is, one has to know that the vectors $v_i$ form a basis.

Comment: Before completing the basis, the "coefficients" $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are not well determined by the first $v_1, \ldots, v_m.$ For example, if you had $v_1 = (1,0,0)$ (i.e. $m = 1,$ $n = 3$) then the vector $(x,y,z)$ has "coordinates" $a_1 = x,$ $a_2 = y$ and $a_3 = z$ for the basis $v_1, (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ but has "coordinates" $a_1 = x, a_2 = y, a_3 = 2z$ for the basis $v_1, (0,1,0), (0,0,\frac{1}{2}).$ If you do not complete the basis, you cannot talk of a unique expansion of $v.$ Thus, you will not have a well-defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i w_i.\tag1$$is useful because you deduce from it that

- $f(v_1)=w_1$ (it follows from $(1)$ if you take $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$)
- $f(v_2)=w_2$ (it follows from $(1)$ if you take $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$)
- $\vdots$
- $f(v_m)=w_m$(it follows from $(1)$ if you take $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, where the $1$ is the $m$<sup>th</sup> coordinate).

And, since you know that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis, you know that such a linear map $f$ exists.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain a little more detailed what you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: I used the fact that, since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, there is a linear map $f\colon V\longrightarrow W$ such that $f(v_1)=w_1$, $f(v_2)=w_2$, ..., $f(v_m)=w_m$, $f(v_{m+1})=0$, ..., $f(v_n)=0$.

Comment: Thanks again! I think it is clear to me now. I am sorry, but I have two more questions (I hope that I am not too annoying). Shouldn't the last equation say $f(v+v')= f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+a'_i) v_i \right)=f(v)+f(v')$? If the given system of vectors is already a basis, does it follow that $f$ is an Isomorphism?

Comment: I don't know what is that “last equation” that you are talking about; there is no equation in my answer or in my comment. And, no, it does not follow that $f$ is an isomorphism. Since $f(v_n)=0$, you can be *sure* that it is *not* an isomorphism (unless $m=n$, and even then it doesn't have to be an isomorphism).

Comment: It's a waste of time. It's part of a justification of the fact that such a function is a linear map. It doesn't make sense, really.